# Finding DC saturation behavior of clamp ferrites

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, saturation, ferrite, clamp

While some chip ferrite datasheets specify maximum current and DC saturation behavior, it seems like many clamp ferrites omit both maximum current specification (which arguably is less critical) but also any notion of the DC saturation behavior.

In my case, I'm looking to attenuate noise on a power LED driver output cable carrying up to a couple of amps and would like to know if the clamp ferrite could saturate. Spontaneously, given only one cable pass and relatively low current I have hard time imagining that the ferrite would saturate or that the impedance curve would be significantly affected (Example ferrites as reference: 74271142S, ESD-SR-100). But, generally speaking:

Is there a way to estimate the saturation behavior of clamp ferrites if no relevant information is provided in the datasheet?

Are there any rules of thumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In my case, I'm looking to attenuate noise on a power LED driver
> output cable carrying up to a couple of amps and would like to know if
> the clamp ferrite could saturate.*

A ferrite clamp is used to clamp a cable that carries forward and return currents. So, in these situations the magneto motive forces from forward and return currents cancel out and saturation does not occur.

Should you **not** be using it as intended i.e. you are only passing either forward or return current through it then, you should find an alternative component where the data is available for this type of application.